# how to access xampp server from internet using dynamic ip address

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp server on my windows 7.
I am connecting internet using HUAWEI Dongle.
I don't have any static IP address.i Want to access my php file from internet example I have connected to internet now I have dynamic IP address like 100.101.73.240 if some one enter 100.101.73.240/home.php in his browser address bar then my home.php page should open in his browser.
What should I do for this give me step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

Local Ip can't work over the internet. It's your intranet network. If you have dynamic internet IP, then you simply configure the Dynamic DNS service. Which you can configure your Internet Router with the following settings (provided by the Dynamic DNS service providers).

1. dyn.com
2. noip.com
3. dynu.com
   many more.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to share IP with someone from your local area network:**

Go to cmd, run ipconfig command, and find your local IP, which should be like 192.168.xxx.yyy. You can easily share it with no worries it will change each time you reset your network.

[image]

**If it's someone from external network:**

You have no power to share your external IP if you have dynamic one, it will change too often, but still it should work for a short connection sessions. To obtain a stable address you would have to register [**a domain**](https://www.google.pl/search?client=opera&hs=cDB&q=free%20domain&oq=free%20domain&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i67k1j0l7j0i67k1.2180.3584.0.3822.11.8.0.3.3.0.109.774.5j3.8.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.10.682...0i131k1j35i39k1j0i10k1.bzyQbOw5Gg8)

Comment: Are you trying to say that he should be also in my local area network.

Comment: I want access xampp from internet from anywhere if visitor is not in my local network doesn't matter. I am connecting internet using airtel sim card